# Derivative of a Matrix Expression with Hadamard

Tags: matrices, derivatives, hadamard-product

I have the following expression at hand:

$1_{nx1}^T (X_{nxk} \circ X_{nxk})(Y_{kx1} \circ Y_{kx1})$

$X$ is a matix, $Y$ is a vector, and $1$ is a vector of ones with indicated dimensions. $\circ$ is the element by element multiplication. Expression evaluates to a scalar.

I would like to take the derivative of the above expression with respect to $Y$.

I think the result should be a vector of same size as $Y$. Matrix cookbook doesn't seem to cover these kind of cases. I am a little stuck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting the trace/Frobenius product with a colon, e.g. $\,A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB),\,$ allows you to write the scalar function in a form that's easy to reduce
$$\eqalign{
\phi
 &= 1:(X\circ X)(y\circ y) \cr
 &= (X\circ X)^T1:(y\circ y) \cr
}$$
Now calculate the differential and the gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
 &= 2(X\circ X)^T1:(y\circ dy) \cr
 &= 2(X\circ X)^T1:Y\,dy \cr
 &= 2\,Y(X\circ X)^T1:dy \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} &= 2\,Y(X\circ X)^T1 \cr
}$$
where $Y={\rm Diag}(y).$

Comment: Sorry. It seems I made a mistake with notation. I meant to use Hadamard instead I used Kronecker. I fixed the question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985734/differentiating-with-hadamard-ax-odot-b. Based on your other answer I think the answer should be $1^T(X\circ X)diag(y)$. No? I don't know why I ended up with a row vector though.

Comment: Sorry, when I initially read the problem, I thought you were using a Kronecker product, not a Hadamard product. So this answer is completely off-track. I will fix it.